# Word2010- hyperlinking within the same folder

Tags: hyperlink

I have a folder containing a Word-document (MS Office 2010), which has hyperlinks to some files within the same folder as the word document. However, these hyperlinks work only on my computer. Someone else with this folder cannot access these hyperlinks. 
I want the links to work on any harddrive which contains this folder. 
What do I do?

Is there any other way to address this problem? Basically the hyperlinks in the word file should work for anyone with the document. Is there some website on which these files can be uploaded, so that clicking on the word-hyperlink points to the corresponding URL?,

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your links are of the form `file://./DocName.ext#location` and then the links should point to the local folder - zip the lot for distribution.

Comment: Thanks a lot! i discovered that u can't link to files within other folders, but it is automatic relative linking if files are within the same folder